# Airpods drops connection or makes sizzle sounds after Monterey upgrade

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, airpods, monterey

I have Airpods 2 for few months and I have been using it without problems till today. Today I installed MacOs Monterrey 12.0.1 and my Airpods started to create issues. Every 5-10 mins there is a sizzle sound either I watch Youtube videos or I listen music in Spotify.

This never happened before Monterey. Also time to time I meet 1 second connection drops in this new OS which also never happened before.

Any ideas how to fix that?

PS. Tested on iPhone, no problem at all.

PS2. While I use XCode and I do debug, when the debug stops at debug point, Airpods sizzle starts. Funny right?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I was the only one experiencing this - my results match yours precisely. I believe it's a Monterey bug since if it were a hardware issue with the AirPods, the sound quality from iPhone / iOS would suffer like it does from macOS.

Hopefully, it will get fixed in the next update if Apple gets enough trouble calls or can reproduce the issue themselves without getting direct feedback from people.